# Azure function validate token in typescript

Tags: typescript, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I'm building a website using Azure Static Web App, the login/registration in being handled by Azure B2C. The API is typescript Azure functions (part of Azure Static web app). I have some API calls that are only accessed when the user is logged in, as such i'm sending the bearer token to the backend.

How can I validate this token against my Azure B2C tenant in the backend (typescript), so that if its valid send back the data to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to vadlidate Azure AD B2C access token, we can use the package `azure-ad-verify-token` to implement it

For example

```
import { verify, VerifyOptions } from 'azure-ad-verify-token';
 
const options: VerifyOptions = {
  jwksUri: 'https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1_signupsignin1',
  issuer: 'https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tennat id>/v2.0/',
  audience: '<Identifies the intended recipient of the token. For Azure AD B2C, the audience is the application ID>'
};
var res = await verify(token, options);
 context.log(res);
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#validation) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-ad-verify-token)